# Is there any continual support from Google on uiautomator?

Tags: android-uiautomator

I don't see any updates to the github for 8 months: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/uiautomator/
There are uiautomator defects filed in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=uiautomator

Is it safe to say that Google has dropped support for this tool?

PS: Is there an email address or contact # that I could get this information from a Google representative?

Answer (score 1):

A quick check shows that the members are still assigning the bugs and enhancements. Check this one for example:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82292&q=uiautomator&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

I don't think it is being dropped.